# Creating two dimensional mutable array in Rust with undefined size

Tags: rust

I can't find a way to do this simple thing in Rust:

```
let mut a: [i32][i32];
a[0][0] = 1;
a[0][1] = 2;
a[1][0] = 8;
```

Comment: You need to use a `Vec<Vec<i32>>`, arrays are fixed size.

Comment: What is `[i32][i32]`?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) it allows you to create collections with various sizes.

```rust
let mut a = vec![
  vec![1, 2],
  vec![3, 4, 5],
];
```

or

```rust
let mut a = Vec::new();
a.push(vec![1, 2]);
a.push(vec![3, 4, 5]);
```

Also, you may create a `Vec` of arrays. It will give you a better performance. But in this case, all the arrays must have the same size

```rust
let mut a = Vec::new();
a.push([1, 2]);
a.push([3, 4]);
```